# Environment.GetFolderPath returns null in WMI provider

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have a decoupled WMI provider (Windows service) that is configured with a file that lives in the C:\ProgramData\CompanyName folder. When the service loads up it uses the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Enviornment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` method to grab the `C:\ProgramData` portion of the path.

While the service is running I attempt to write to the same file, through a WMI call into the service, using the same method call but this time is fails; returning null.

Is there something about the fact that I'm now running in the context of WMI that causes this to happen?

Comment: Yes, beware the user account.  GetFolderPath gets dinky for LocalSystem.

Comment: The user account calling the WMI? Because the service user is the same for both calls.

Comment: @Hans: what do you mean exactly?  Is it not good to use `Environment.GetFolderPath()`?  What about `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu)` (current user path)

Comment: Not for system accounts, LocalSystem doesn't have a start menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problems, however perhaps I can offer a solution. 
Slightly different usage attempting to get special folders on a web server to write temporary files but indeed having issues with the user that it runs as (runs under the DefualtAppPool domain group rather than a user even)

Had blanks returned even on my local win 7 machine for attempts to get

```
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

However i did manage to use the 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData` 
method to get what i wanted, it has several different options to find different folders in the file structure but instead of being user based it works based on the application or i suppose the system.
I pretty sure its just as "clean" a method to use as the Environment.GetFolderPath method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx

One of the the enumerations is bound to achieve what you are looking for.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("ProgramFiles");
```

or @JohnB

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("StartMenu");
```